# Mixed C++/CLI code with Berkeley DB

Tags: database, visual-c++, c++-cli, berkeley-db, mixed-mode

I'm traying to use Berkeley DB in C++/CLI with `/clr` mode. I wrote this code:

**Edit:**

```
// DB_test1.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"libdb51")
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Db SigDb(0,0);
    unsigned int oFlags= DB_CREATE;
    SigDb.open(NULL,"SigDb.db",0,DB_BTREE,oFlags,0);
    String^ HexSig="D8B1048900ABFF8B";
    wchar_t* a=( wchar_t* )Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(HexSig).ToPointer() ;
    wchar_t* A=( wchar_t* )Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(HexSig).ToPointer();;

    Dbt key1(&a,100);
    Dbt data1(&A,100);

    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(A));
    int ret= SigDb.put(NULL,&key1,&data1, DB_NOOVERWRITE);
    if(ret==DB_KEYEXIST){
        Console::WriteLine("You are trying to insert an exist key!");
    }


    wchar_t DDData[200];
    Dbt getKey, getData;
    getKey.set_data(&a);

    getKey.set_size(100);
    getData.set_data(DDData);
    getData.set_ulen(200);
    getData.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(a));
    if(SigDb.get(NULL,&getKey,&getData,0)==DB_NOTFOUND)
        Console::WriteLine("Not Found !");
    else
        Console::WriteLine(" {0}",Marshal::PtrToStringUni((IntPtr)DDData));


    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled successfully but it shows wrong output. I am just traying to store `String^ HexSig="D8B1048900ABFF8B";`  in `SigDb.db` and then directly read the same string and print it!. The result does not appear like `D8B1048900ABFF8B` as it expected, but it appears as a random string. Any ideas?

**After Editing:**
This segment of code is always executed `Console::WriteLine("Not Found !");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two issues with your application:

1) The two calls to Marshal::FreeHGlobal are made before the contents of the buffers are used. You shouldn't free 'A' until after the put operation, and you shouldn't free 'a' until after both the put and get operations.

2) You are storing the pointers in Berkeley DB, rather than the strings themselves. That's due to the Dbt constructor calls. You're application is:
Dbt key1(&a,100);
It should be:
Dbt key1(a, 100);

Similarly for the getKey.set_data method - it should use the pointer, not a reference to the pointer.

Once I made the above changes to your application, it ran as expected.

Regards,
Alex Gorrod
Oracle Berkeley DB

Comment: Thank you very much Alex!. The problem has been solved by following your notes!

Answer (score 1):

You use Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(), the converted string is a wchar_t*, not a char*.  A wide string with the Unicode codepoints encoded in utf16.  To get a char* you need StringToHGlobalAnsi().

Do consider that this is a lossy conversion, dbase engines have been Unicode enabled for well over a decade now.  Another serious problem is that you don't release the memory allocated for this string, calling Marshal::FreeHGlobal() in a finally block is required. You also should technically use GlobalLock() to convert the returned HGLOBAL to a pointer, consider Marshal::StringToCoTaskMemXxx.

Comment: @Hans i did some modifications you suggested and i can not find the string in the database, it always shows This segment of code is always executed `Console::WriteLine("Not Found !");`

Comment: There are few odds that I can help you find it back.  If you didn't get an error return from put() then something was written.  Do note that your error checking code is not okay, you only trap DB_KEYEXIST.

Comment: I am sure that something similar to the content of `String^ HexSig` was written to the database (or the exact `String^ HexSig` content). I feel that the problem is in reading parameters but i can't determine where it is exactly!!

Comment: You did replace PtrToStringUni() with PtrToStringAnsi(), right?

Comment: I've asked one of our C++ engineers to take a look at this question. In the future, you may want to post questions like this to the BDB forum at http://bit.ly/eIREhr, where there are lots of BDB users, development and support engineers monitoring the forum.

Comment: @:dsegleau ,I have put my question at BDB forum, thanks dsegleau for your suggestion.